Is it possible to create a GitHub personal access token that represents the system in contrast to an actual user?
We want to create a Personal Access Token (PAT) to invoke workflows from other workflows. The problem is PATs are associated with a user and a user is not accessing the workflow; GitHub Actions is.
In some systems, it is possible to create identities that represent automatons. For example, users do not run CI/CD processes, Jenkins, ConcourseCI or other systems run them. "System Accounts" or "Service Accounts" are commonly assigned to these systems to grant "Jenkins" access to a repo, or "ConcourseCI" access to a webhook.
Is it possible to create a PAT in GitHub representing a system account and not a user and grant that automaton access?
